# Designing a filter interface with a template method pattern

Tags: java, templates, design-patterns, filter

I have done a filter interface that filters out all the strings that have more than 3 letters without any particular pattern. How do i now define a abstract class Filter with a public method filter that calls the method acept that can be implemented in different ways? All of this using Template method pattern?

```
public class WordFilter extends Filter{

    public boolean accept(String obj){

        return(((String) obj).length() <= 3);
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RunHere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] theArray = { "oig3", "jt3jjt3", "wee", "02ri", "Adam", "lel", "32", "k" };

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theArray));

        WordFilter filt = new WordFilter();

        String[] resultat = filter(theArray, filt);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultat));

    }

    public static String[] filter(String[] a, Filter f){

        String x;
        int count = 0;
        int pos = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            x = a[i];
            if (x.length() < 4) {
                count++;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Count is :" + count);

        String[] filtered = new String[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (f.accept(a[i])) {
                filtered[pos] = a[i];
                pos++;
            }

        }

        return filtered;

    }
}
```

```java
public abstract class Filter {
    abstract boolean accept(String x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Template Method Pattern defines the skeleton of an algorithm in a method, deferring some steps to subclasses.
But in the problem that you have given, i see that there is only one step( finding Strings of size n). i.e there is no step before or after finding string of size n.

If Something was there(multiple tasks), i would have done it like below. Which would implement the Template pattern.

```
public abstract class Filter {
    abstract boolean accept(String x);

    void BeforeStep() {
        // Do something
    }

    void AfterStep() {
        // do something
    }

}


public static String[] filter(String[] a, Filter f) {

        String x;
        int count = 0;
        int pos = 0;

        **f.BeforeStep();**

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            x = a[i];
            if (x.length() < 4) {
                count++;
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Count is :" + count);

        String[] filtered = new String[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (f.accept(a[i])) {
                filtered[pos] = a[i];
                pos++;
            }

        }

        f.AfterStep();        

        return filtered;
    }
```